# matplotlib plot yahoo chart api graph plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am just starte learn matplotlib. i am try to plot yahoo char api plot stock. i am try this program but it is not working...there is my program

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def graph():
    date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, valuep = np.loadtxt('/home/najeeb/Desktop/table.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True,
                          converters={0: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})

   fig = plt.figure()
   ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, axisbg='w')
   plt.plot_date(x=date, y=value, fmt='-')

   plt.title('title')
   plt.ylabel('value')
   plt.xlabel('date')
   plt.show()
graph()
```

[here is CSV file](http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&d=9&e=14&f=2008&g=d&a=8&b=7&c=1984&ignore=.csv)

please guide me how to solve this problem and there another any way to plot stock graph...thank you

Answer (score 0):

The CSV file looked like this:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2014-10-17,97.50,99.00,96.81,97.67,68032200,97.67
2014-10-16,95.55,97.72,95.41,96.26,72110700,96.26
2014-10-15,97.97,99.15,95.18,97.54,100875400,97.54
```

Your code `np.loadtxt()` was trying to parse the header 'Date' as a date, which didn't work because that string wasn't a valid date value, so I used `skiprows=1` to skip the header.

The other problem was, the CSV has 7 columns, and in your tuple you were unpacking only 6 values

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import urllib2


url = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&d=9&e=14&f=2008&g=d&a=8&b=7&c=1984&ignore=.csv'

def graph():
    date, open, high, low, close, volume, adj_close = np.loadtxt(urllib2.urlopen(url), skiprows=1, delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, axisbg='w')
    plt.plot_date(x=date, y=adj_close, fmt='-')

    plt.title('Apple, 1984 to 2008')
    plt.ylabel('Adjusted close')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.show()

graph()
```

Comment: @NajeebChoudhary, Welcome to StackOverflow, please accept the answer if it solves your problem, have fun with Python!